# Is there a way to autocomplete interface implementation template on Monodevelop Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Say I have an interface:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
  void Foo();
  int Bar { get; }
}
```

In my class:

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
  //Is there a way to automatically generate the below "templates"
  //through pressing a button or a shortcut?

  public void Foo()
  {

  }

  public int Bar 
  {
    get
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Normally I would just type it out, but for cases where the interfaces are somewhat long and if I have to do it across many different classes it gets a tad tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just right click the `ISomeInterface`.

[image]